# How to handle NULL, which is being received from main. C++

Tags: c++, function, null

I am new to C++. I have a function called `isValid(const char str[]);`

```
int isValid (const char str[])
{
  int len = strlen (str);

  if (strlen (str) != 10)
     return 0;
  if (!isdigit (str[i]))
     return 0;
  if (str==NULL)
     return 0;
  if (atol(str)==1234567890)
     return 1;
}
```

sample MAIN:

```
int main(void)
{
   char test[10];
   cout<<"Testing NULL"<<endl;
   cout<< isValid(NULL)<<endl;

   cout<<"Testing isValid"<<endl<<"Enter test: ";
   cin>>test;
   cout<<isValid(test)<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I am getting this:

> Testing NULL
>
> Segmentation fault

How do i implement NULL.
Thanks!

Comment: Add a check for `NULL`, and take appropriate action.

Comment: What would you like to have happen? Either check if the value passed in is `NULL`, and deal with it in an appropriate way, or let it crash...

Answer (score 3):

The order of tests in `isValid` is wrong - you need to test for `NULL` first before calling `strlen` or dereferencing `str`.

You also had another couple of errors:

`isValid` needs to add a return value for the case that none of your `if` conditions are satisfied.  I'd have expected this to generate a warning.  If it didn't, compiling with warnings enabled (`/W4` for MSVC, `-Wall` for gcc) would have flagged it.

`i` isn't defined so `isdigit(str[i])` wouldn't compile.  My updated code (below) shows how to confirm that each character in `str` is a digit

```
int isValid (const char str[])
{
    if (str==NULL)
        return 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    if (len != 10)
        return 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (!isdigit (str[i]))
            return 0;
    }
    if (atol(str)==1234567890)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I copied that from the question and hadn't noticed it wouldn't compile.  Will update/fix in a sec

Answer (score 2):

Given what your `isValid` really checks for, it appears that it can be simplified quite a bit. Specifically, the only 10-character string of all digits that `atoi` can convert to the number 1234567890 appears to be the string "1234567890", so we might as well just test for that directly:

```
int isvalid(char const *input) { 
    return (input != NULL) && (strcmp(input, "1234567890") == 0);
}
```

Comment: LOL. I'd guess the content is work in progress just sidetracked by crash ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
int isValid (const char str[])
{
    if (str==NULL)
     return 0;

  int len = strlen (str);

  if (strlen (str) != 10)
     return 0;
  if (!isdigit (str[i]))
     return 0;
  //if (str==NULL)   /// this should be the first check
  //  return 0;      ///
  if (atol(str)==1234567890)
     return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int isValid (const char str[])
{
  if (str == NULL) return 0;  //add this line

  int len = strlen (str);

  if (strlen (str) != 10)
     return 0;
  if (!isdigit (str[i]))
     return 0;
 // if (str==NULL)   //remove this line
 //    return 0;     //remove this line
  if (atol(str)==1234567890)
     return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with design: making up your mind about NULL in the case. Is it a valid input for this function? If not, then do not call it like that in main, it's violation of preconditions.

If you decide NULL is okay to test and isValid shall act on it, say returning 0, add that test in the first place. But before that change the signature to take `const char*`. Yes, internally they are about the same, array can not be passed and really converts to pointer. But for humans it documents the intent differently.  In my book if the function takes an array, it must be an actual array, no matter what other magic the language does. While using a pointer indicates it is fair game to expect NULL.

While you're at it, change the return type to bool, as in C++ predicate functions supposed to be. And accordingly return false and true instead of 0 and 1.

Your third if checks for NULL, but in the first you already called strlen. Move it up, and access violation will go away.

Store len in const int or rather in const auto. It really will be size_t or unsigned something, but the rest of code is not concerned. Then use that len constant rather than calling strlen again.

I don't get the second test, as there's no i around so it should not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have used is allowed by the language on the understanding that the compiler is going to ignore it and use a pointer instead, because that's the only thing it can mean in this context:

```
int isValid (const char str[])
```

See http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html.

The compiler treats this exactly as:

```
int isValid(const char* str)
```

(Because: Your syntax suggests you want the function to start with an unknown number of characters on the stack)

If you absolutely know the array is going to have a fixed size and you want all the privileges and responsibilities of having an array rather than a pointer, you can either do:

```
int isValid(const char str[10]) // takes a copy of the array every invocation,
// I bet your next question is "why don't my changes stick"
```

or

```
int isValid(char (&str)[10])    // whee, it's an array
```